# Error char arrays from RandomAccessFile in Java

Tags: java, arrays, randomaccessfile

I'm using `RandomAccessFile` to browse thru a series of records in a `.dat` file. I'm using the GUI interface. I have no problem writing the Strings from the `textFields` into the file, but when I try to read it back into the fields, the first record called looks fine, but by the third record the fields just display some strange encoded characters. Does this have something to do with an offset? Does it have something to do with the way I increment through the records? I've looked all over the web today and I'm stuck. Here's a sample of my code.

Read/write methods:

```
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class StudentFile6 {

    private final int R_SIZE = 70;
    private final RandomAccessFile studentFile;

    public StudentFile6(String fileName) throws IOException {
        studentFile = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw");
    }

    public void writeStudentFile(Student6 student) throws IOException {

        studentFile.seek(studentFile.length());
        if (student.getFirst().length() > 15) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                studentFile.writeChar(student.getFirst().charAt(i));
            }
        } else {
            studentFile.writeChars(student.getFirst());
            for (int i = 0; i < (15 - student.getFirst().length()); i++) {
                studentFile.writeChar(' ');
           }
        }
        if (student.getLast().length() > 15) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                studentFile.writeChar(student.getLast().charAt(i));
            }
        } else {
            studentFile.writeChars(student.getLast());
            for (int i = 0; i < (15 - student.getLast().length()); i++) {
                studentFile.writeChar(' ');
            }
        }
        if (student.getID().length() > 5) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            studentFile.writeChar(student.getID().charAt(i));
            }
        } else {
            studentFile.writeChars(student.getID());
            for (int i = 0; i < (5 - student.getID().length()); i++) {
                studentFile.writeChar(' ');
            }
        }
    }

    public Student6 readStudentFile(int count) throws IOException, 
        EOFException{

        char[] firstCharArray = new char[15];
        char[] lastCharArray = new char[15];
        char[] idCharArray = new char[5];

        studentFile.seek(count * 35);
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            firstCharArray[i] = studentFile.readChar();
        }
        String first = new String(firstCharArray);

        studentFile.seek(count * 35 + 30);
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            lastCharArray[i] = studentFile.readChar();
        }
        String last = new String(lastCharArray);

        studentFile.seek(count * 35 + 60);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            idCharArray[i] = studentFile.readChar();
        }
        String ID = new String(idCharArray);

        Student6 student = new Student6(first, last, ID);
        return student;        
    }
```

Here's what I think is the relevant code from the class that calls these methods:

```
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FinalExam6 extends JFrame {

    private int recordNum = 0;
    //there are more static variables, but this is the only one i use to write 
    //and read 


//lots of code setting up my GUI interface....

//Here's the code that handles writing my RandomAccessFile:

private class AddStudentButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            String first = txtFirst.getText();
            String last = txtLast.getText();
            String ID = txtID.getText();
            Student6 student = new Student6(first, last, ID);
            StudentFile6 studentFile = new StudentFile6("StudentInfo.dat");
            student.setFirst(first);
            student.setLast(last);
            student.setID(ID);
            studentFile.writeStudentFile(student);
            txtFirst.setText("");
            txtLast.setText("");
            txtID.setText("");
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    }


//Here's the code that reads it:

private class BrowseStudentListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            recordNum++;
            StudentFile6 studentFile = new StudentFile6("StudentInfo.dat");
            txtFirst.setText
                (studentFile.readStudentFile(recordNum).getFirst());
            txtLast.setText(studentFile.readStudentFile(recordNum).getLast());
            txtID.setText(studentFile.readStudentFile(recordNum).getID());
            studentFile.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
```

I realize i might be missing some brackets in here or there doing copy/past. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your record size is 70 bytes (`private final int R_SIZE = 70;`). That matches with writing 35 chars (at 2 bytes for each char).

However for calculating the position of a record you write

```
studentFile.seek(count * 35);
```

which will place your read pointer in the middle of some record for odd count values.

At least the (unnecessary) line

```
studentFile.seek(count * 35 + 60);
```

should have told you that something is wrong!